# How do I confirm my Tezos wallet is up to date; most current version etc.?

Tags: wallets

Step by step instructions for each commonly-used XTZ wallet, to confirm you're using the latest version with the most current

to include:
-- how to check to determine the installed version.
-- link page with updates/downloads
-- how to determine if an upgrade is critical
-- any instructions on upgrading etc

Comment: Would be better to ask for a specific Wallet. "Commonly used" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

For Galleon you can check their Github Releases wiki [here](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Deployments/wiki/Galleon:-Releases).

At this link you can find the old releases, as well as the most recent releases. The most recent release is Version 0.7.0b (Jan 17, 2019).